# Laravel - prepared statement contains too many placeholders

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im wondering if someone could give me a hand.

I have written an import script, it works fine for a small number of points, but when i start importing large numbers, i get the following error:

```
General error: 1390 Prepared statement contains too many placeholders
```

The code that im using to import is as follows:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {

    $insert[] = array(

        'userid' => User::current()->id,
        'lati' => $item[0],
        'long' => $item[1],
        'streetNumber' => $item[2],
        'streetName' => $item[3],
        'country' => $item[6],
        'state' => $item[5],
        'pcode' => $item[7],
        'suburb' => $suburb,
        'created_at' => new DateTime,
        'updated_at' => new DateTime

    );

}

if(DB::table('mytable')->insert($insert))
{

    return true;

} else {

    return false;           

}
```

Any help with figuring out how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's limit of placeholders (`?` bindings) in the query of ca 65k. So   just do the insert in batches.

Answer (score -6):

```
function addData($items) {
    $itemsTemp = [];
    if (count > 1000) {
        $itemsTemp = array_slice($items, 1000);
        $items = array_slice($items, 0, 1000);
    }
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        $insert[] = [

            'userid' => User::current()->id,
            'lati' => $item[0],
            'long' => $item[1],
            'streetNumber' => $item[2],
            'streetName' => $item[3],
            'country' => $item[6],
            'state' => $item[5],
            'pcode' => $item[7],
            'suburb' => $suburb,
            'created_at' => new DateTime,
            'updated_at' => new DateTime

        ];

    }
    if (DB::table('mytable')->insert($insert)) {
        if ($itemsTemp) {
            addData($itemsTemp);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;


}
```

Comment: Code with comments or explanation really isn't helpful.

Comment: pls provide some explanation